# Database Design For Developing 'Quiz' Web Application using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, forms

So, I'm trying to learn PHP and MySQL (I have a basic understanding of both; I've read the first half of both Head First SQL and Head First PHP & MySQL) and I figure the best way to solidify my knowledge is by building something rather than reading.

With that in mind, I would like to create a basic webpage that connects to a MySQL database on a server.  I will build a basic HTML form and allow users to input basic information, such as: last_name, first_name, email, birthday, gender.

**My problem is** I don't know how to design a database that will record the results of a basic quiz - I want just 5 multiple-choice problems.  Eventually, I would like to display the results of the user versus the previous users' results.

If you could help me understand how to design table(s) for a 5-question Quiz I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I would start with 4 simple tables:

**Users**

```
- user_id        auto integer
- regtime        datetime
- username       varchar
- useremail      varchar
- userpass       varchar
```

**Questions**

```
- question_id    auto integer
- question       varchar
- is_active      enum(0,1)
```

**Question_choices**

```
- choice_id        auto integer
- question_id      Questions.question_id
- is_right_choice  enum(0,1)
- choice           varchar
```

**User_question_answers**

```
- user_id        Users.user_id
- question_id    Questions.question_id
- choice_id      Question_choices.choice.id
- is_right       enum(0,1)
- answer_time    datetime
```

My thought on this table design is:

- table `Users` is for storing registered user.
- table `Questions` is for storing all your questions.

  - It has `is_active` so that you can selectively display only active questions (using `WHERE is_active = '1'`)
- table `question_choices` is for storing all available options. It has `is_right_choice` which defines what choice is the right answer for particular question.
- Table `User_question_answers` is for storing answer from your user.

  - It has `is_right` for faster lookup, to see whether that particular question and answer choice is right (based on `is_right_choice` previously defined).
  - It also has `answer_time` just to note when that particular user answer the question.

Comment: Wow!  I love the simplicity of your design, it's a good starting point for me.  The only part I don't quite understand is the 'is_active' column of the question table.  I'm not sure how I would use this, other than that, I understand how it all fits together.  Thanks!

Comment: For the is_active question, you would basically SELECT from question WHERE is_active = 1 in order to get the questions to display.. i.e. if is_active is set to 0, the question is not active and not be displayed.

Comment: Can you recommend a pilot project?

Comment: So I am seeking an answer to: "Why is this solution better than keeping question and 4 multiple answer choices in the same table"? So my tables could be( q_id, q, op1, opt2, opt3, opt4, correct_opt). Doesn't it reduce the overload of a join?

Comment: @SambhavSharma Its done to have variable options not just four

Comment: Simple and effective ! Great answer !

Answer (score 16):

I am not sure how new you are to programming in general, but even if you are just getting started, I would recommend you use a framework.

Using a framework will guide you by providing best-practice implementations of the tools you'll need in your project.

I personally use [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) for php projects, and I would suggest you check out [their guides and tutorials](http://symfony.com/get_started). Symfony is a well-established framework and it's based on widely accepted designs.

To answer your question more directly, though, I would suggest something like this for your application:

```
 - user
  - id (PK)
  - last_name
  - first_name
  - email
  - gender


 - quiz
  - id (PK)
  - title


 - quiz_question
  - id (PK)
  - quiz_id (FK)
  - text

 - quiz_question_option
  - id (PK)
  - quiz_question_id (FK)
  - text
  - is_correct

 - quiz_user_answer
   - id (PK)
   - quiz_question_id (FK)
   - quiz_question_option_id  // this is the answer.
```

The above would allow you to define multiple quizes each having multiple questions and create answer sets (a user's set of answers to a quiz) and record each answer.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response.  I am having trouble understanding the function of the quiz_user_answer_set table.  Also, is the'answer' column in the quiz_user_answer table supposed to connect with the 'quiz_question_option_id'?  Thanks for you help...

Comment: Hi, I left quiz_user_answer_set by mistake after an edit.. it wasn't needed. And yes, the answer column is a foreign key to quiz_question_option and I should've named it "quiz_question_option_id". :)

Comment: I think the `quiz_user_answer` should also have a reference to the `user` who answered the question. @0x6A75616E

Comment: Would this support question with multiple answers? If not, what changes would be required?

Comment: So on every choice selection of a particular question, shall we store that record into the database only? Does it comes under best practices to hit the database on every question choice submission? what if thousands of users are attending that vary quiz test?

Answer (score 7):

This was also the first project I did in PHP/MySQL about 8 years ago.

Your first solution is to code the database to exactly match your form. So, you want to record users and quiz submissions, so it's going to look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY, 
  password VARCHAR(8), 
  email VARCHAR(255), 
  birthday DATE, 
  gender ENUM('M', 'F')
);

CREATE TABLE quiz_answers (
  username VARCHAR(16) REFERENCES users,
  question1 VARCHAR(10),
  question2 INT,
  question3 ENUM('YES', 'NO', 'MAYBE'),
  question4 BOOLEAN,
  question5 VARCHAR(25),
  submitted_at DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (username, submitted_at)
);
```

So this is just recording the bare minimum: the user and the quiz submissions. I've given types for the answers which you would have to make specific to your actual quiz. I've also made a response keyed off the user and the moment they submitted it; you're be more likely to use a surrogate key (`AUTO_INCREMENT`), but I like to resist surrogates as much as possible.

Right off the bat there is a 1NF violation: `questionN`. If you were doing this right, you would name these columns after what they mean, not just which question they are. But normalizing this is really the next step towards forms that are extensible, but track history.

So the next thing you would notice is that really a quiz is a collection of questions, each of which has a collection of possible answers. And then a form submission really relates a set of selected answers to their questions, on a particular quiz form, by a particular quiz user. This sounds like a four-way relationship: user, quiz, question, answer. You can trim out one of those if you don't mind repeating questions on different quizes, but for the sake of completeness, let's go down this road. Replace `quiz_answers` above with this:

```
CREATE TABLE questions (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  question TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE answers (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  question_id INTEGER REFERENCES questions,
  answer VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE quizzes (
  name VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

We don't really have any special metadata for a quiz, so it's just a name for now.

So now you need a one-to-many relationship from questions to answers and from quizzes to questions.

```
CREATE TABLE question_answers (
  question_id INTEGER REFERENCES questions,
  answer_id INTEGER REFERENCES answers,
  idx INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (question_id, answer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE quiz_questions (
  quiz_name VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES quizzes,
  question_id INTEGER REFERENCES questions,
  idx INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (quiz_name, question_id)
);
```

The tricky part, like mentioned above, is the higher order relationship between the user and the form submission, and the link from the form questions to user answers. I've decided to separate this into two tables to avoid some repetition.

```
CREATE TABLE quiz_submissions (
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(16) REFERENCES users,
  quiz_name VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES quizzes,
  submitted_at DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE submission_answer (
  submission_id INTEGER REFERENCES quiz_submissions,
  question_id INTEGER REFERENCES questions,
  answer_id INTEGER REFERENCES answers,
  PRIMARY KEY (submission_id, question_id)
);
```

This is pretty well normalized at this point. You can see that it is also going to be a bit harder to query. To get all the questions out for a quiz, you'll have to join from the quiz to the questions. You can either join from there onto the answers to do one big query to get all the data you need to build the form (along with having to do more post-processing) or you can hit the database one more time for each question and do less post-processing. I can argue either way. To get all of a particular users answers out, you're going to have to select from user_submissions with the quiz ID and the user name to the submission_answer table to the question and the answer the user chose. So the querying is going to get interesting quickly. You'll lose your fear of joins, if you have one.

I hope this won't put you off relational databases too much; by doing this you are, in effect, doing a relational model inside the relational model, albeit a restricted form.

I realize using a lot of natural keys like I have done above is a bit unorthodox these days. However, I recommend you try it, at least while you're getting started, because it will make it much easier to see how the joins have to work if they're not all integers in the range 1-10.

Answer (score 2):

Well, right now i'm in a development stage and still encounter some problems (i.e. synchronizing round states between server and client), but it may make some help to you
[image]

P.S.: do not store passwords in database, like in the picture above - store passwords hashes instead

Comment: Hi, can you please share which software you used for the above database modeling?
is it freeware?

Comment: For those who would like to use software for thier Entity Relationship Diagrams like the one above, you could use [dbdiagram](http://dbdiagram.io) @krishna